# Python error trying to get colors from text file in list

Tags: python

I keep getting a syntax error and it highlights the 1 in “def list(1)” help! I need to take a letter as input, fill list color with colors starting with whatever letter, and display the list of colors to the user.

```
colors = [ ]

def letter( ):    
    part_one = str(input("What is the first letter of the color?: "))    
    part_two = part_one.upper( )    
    return part_two

#Global colors.

def list(1):
    color = open("Colors.txt", 'r')
    for line in colors:
        if line[0] == 1:
            colors.append(line.rstrip())
        color.close
        return colors

def main( ):
    search = letter( )
    color = list(search)
    print(colors)

main( )
```

Comment: `list` is a python keyword. Don't use it as a function name

Comment: thanks, how do I change my user name?

Answer (score 0):

The reason `def list(1):` is highlighting as a syntax error is that it's a syntax error.

What goes inside the parentheses for a function definition is the function's [*parameters*](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-parameter). These are the names for local variables that you can use to access the arguments that the caller gives you.

For example:

```
def spam(count):
    for _ in count:
        print('Spam!')

spam(5)
```

The `count` is a parameter that gets the argument value `5` when I call `spam(5)`.

The number `1` can't be used as a variable ([you wouldn't want to reassign `1` to be a name for `5`, would you?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INTERCAL)), so it also can't be used as a parameter.

I'm not sure what you actually *wanted* to do there. You're calling the function with `search`, which is a single-letter string. so maybe something like this:

```
def list(letter):
    color = open("Colors.txt", 'r')
    for line in colors:
        if line[0] == letter:
            colors.append(line.rstrip())
        color.close
        return colors
```